# Is there a way to make a SOAP call in Python and not wait for the return?

Tags: python, soap, flask, suds

I have a simple Flask application that uses SOAP calls to retrieve data and kick off a long running server process. Using SUDS, I've been able to make the call to get the data, parse it into JSON and return it to the application.

The second part is where I am getting stuck. I just want to kick off the server job and return  immediately since I have another process polling the server for status (some of these jobs run for hours). I've read some posts about making asynchronous calls with Twisted or using a queue based approach but I don't need a callback when the process completes because of the polling.

Is there a way to simply make the call and quit?

Comment: A specific code snippet would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a flask [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Comment: I think this is probably the best way to handle it from this end. However, in the end, it was much simpler to write a wrapper around the service being called to return immediately with a status message indicating that the job was successfully started.